# What's the song when Gaara cries out in episode 297?

Tags: naruto, music

What is the background music themed in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 297 ([Link to Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-297-a-fathers-hope-a-mothers-love-615351)) at time 19:29 when Gaara cries out?

It is very heart touching. I really need it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unreleased soundtrack called ["A Mother's love"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdGZccggstI). I've linked the name to a youtube video of it.